# Change ios project target name when build app with jenkins

Tags: ios, jenkins, executable, publishing

My team use jenkins to build many app from just one source code, because of that all apps after build have the same process name (Executable file get from Target_Name), when we try to open few of them iOS refuse to open because all of them have the same process name.
Any one have any ideas about this issue.

Comment: Why don't you create different targets for same app, it will allow you to have different configuration for each app. Refer [this blog for multiple targets](http://www.itexico.com/blog/bid/99497/iOS-Mobile-Development-Using-Xcode-Targets-to-Reuse-the-Code)

Comment: Thanks @DipenPanchasara for your advice, but using multiple target does not solve my problem. We build about hundred apps and each of them use a User-Defined Key in info.plist file to load different data to display. That why we use jenkins to build app and each time we build a new app we just need to input that value on jenkins not to create a a whole new target in Xcode.